# Duplicate type 'master' found in assembly

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, aspnet-merge

Previously, we were on .net 2.0 and aspnet_merge build was working fine. Now after upgrading to .net 4.0, when we are trying to build our code using aspnet_merge, it throws following error

Duplicate type 'master' found in assembly.

It is a master page and I have throughly checked for duplicacy and there is none..

Plz suggest..

Answer (score 0):

take help from here -
http://dreamlusion.wordpress.com/2008/07/06/an-error-occurred-when-merging-assemblies-access-to-the-path-is-denied/

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9364/Merging-NET-assemblies-using-ILMerge

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue in VS 2012 with 2 aspx files:

- Foo_Bar.aspx
- Foo/Bar.aspx

What fixed it for me was to check off `Precompile during publishing`. As the screenshot shows, it is set not to merge:

[image: Advanced Precompile Settings]

**If you still have issues** try renaming class in the code-behind (eg, from `Foo_Bar` to `Foo_Bar_Old` and update the aspx page tag to match: `<%@ Page ... Inherits="Foo_Bar_Old" %>`)